# Qt TreeView problem when used with sort model

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I have a problem where i did not find a solution so far, actually the question is when and for what `QModelIndex` we have to call `beginInsertColumns` and similar functions. 
My example is the standard Qt example from here:
http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-itemviews-editabletreemodel-example.html

It is also delivered with every qt installation, e.g. C:\Qt\Qt5.12.0\Examples\Qt-5.12.0\widgets\itemviews\editabletreemodel

When just executed, it works fine, but now lets insert a `QSortFilterProxyModel`, just to make it sortable. We change the MainWindow c'tor to

```
...
QFile file(":/default.txt");
file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);
TreeModel *model = new TreeModel(headers, file.readAll());
file.close();

QSortFilterProxyModel* sort = new QSortFilterProxyModel( this );
sort->setSourceModel( model );

view->setModel( sort );
...
```

Now execute the example, expand one or two of the root nodes and select the menu entry "insert column" you will see, that only the root nodes have a new column, all their children do not have the new column. It works without the proxy. Now my question, do i have to emit `beginInsertColumns` for every `QModelIndex` that has children?

How can i fix this?
Note, this is not only a problem with qt 5.12, but also with many earlier releases.

Comment: I've only had a quick look at the example code but it always appears to access the model via `view->model()`.  If so, I suspect you may actually be trying to add a column to the proxy rather than the `TreeModel`.  Otherwise this really needs a [mcve].

Comment: Sure, but since the sort proxy is a proxy, it shouldnot matter. Anyway, the problem remains when using the TreeModel directly.

Comment: Try running your model into a QAbstractItemModelTester.

Comment: I did, everything is fine. Moreover the model is the standard qt example, it should be correct.

Comment: `Now my question, do i have to emit beginInsertColumns for every QModelIndex that has children?` *YES*. See this picture: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/images/modelview-models.png , a model in Qt is basically a tree of 2D tables. (For convention, tree models expand only under the first column). But anyhow, if you need 2 columns in a child, you need begin/end insert columns in the parent as wel.

Comment: Tried that, and it seems to work so far. If that is the wanted solution i think the example code should be fixed. In that case the example tree model is broken.

Answer (score 0):

I've always had problems using QSortFilterProxyModel, and as far as I understood they are often related to the index mapping between with the source model.

I managed to solve it using the QSortFilterProxyModel::invalidate() method that will reset the mapping, without spoiling the current state of the view.

Modify the MainWindow::insertColumn as follows:

```
bool MainWindow::insertColumn()
{
    QAbstractItemModel *model = view->model();
    int column = view->selectionModel()->currentIndex().column();

    bool changed = false;
    // Insert a column in the parent item.
    QSortFilterProxyModel* sfpm = qobject_cast<QSortFilterProxyModel*>(model);
    if (sfpm)
    {
        changed = sfpm->insertColumn(column + 1);
        if (changed)
            sfpm->setHeaderData(column + 1, Qt::Horizontal, QVariant("[No header]"), Qt::EditRole);

        sfpm->invalidate();
    }

    updateActions();
    return changed;
}
```

It is not an optimal solution, and I don't know if there is a better way, but works for me.

Comment: sure, this is a solution. But in my real application the tree model changes due to external signals and the model should not know about the following sort proxy. Sure, there are workarounds but it would be great if it just works